Enabling DLSS for UE 4.27.2
I currently have a UE 4.27.2 project that I'd like to enable DLSS for, I'm not familiar with github and only been using unreal engine directly from the epic launcher so would really appreciate some help to get it setup properly.
I found this from Nvidia:
https://developer.nvidia.com/downloads/assets/gameworks/downloads/secure/dlss/getting-started-with-nvidia-dlss-3.7-for-ue-4.27.pdf
I created a github account and linked it to my epic account as instructed in the steps, however I'm not sure where to go from there, should I compile UE 4.27.2 myself which I've never done before or can I modify the one from the launcher, this is all new territory to me so I apologize if this seems like something that should be obvious.
So need to know what should I do for both unreal engine 4.27.2 and the plug-in (what to download/install) in order to run my current project and enable the plug-in in it.
Any help would be appreciated!

There is no need to recompile the engine, just place the downloaded DLSS plugins (plural because there are various related plugins in that distribution) in the Plugins folder under your project main folder, then launch the uproject file as usual.
Unreal will detect the new plugins being present but not built and will ask to build them. In order to build them, you need to have Visual Studio installed and configured for Unreal development in C++.
If you get a compilation error, you need to temporarily rename the plugin folder to something different than Plugins (e.g. _Plugins), start the project via the uproject file, then add a Dummy C++ class (can be of any type, like None) via the File Menu.
Once the class has been added, close everything and from the uproject file choose to create the visual studio project file. This will re-include the plugins in the solution.
Open the updated .sln file and, from within Visual Studio, launch a build of the solution. It will build the Plugins for you showing in the output window how the process is going. In case of errors you need to solve them and Build again. Eventually all the plugins will compile.
Once all plugins have been properly built, close Visual Studio and launch your project again from the uproject file. It will launch and load the Plugins with it.

Thank you so much for replying and you were the only one! I'm trying to follow your steps but I think the content that I downloaded from github wasn't directly to the plug-ins?
Here's a couple of images of what I downloaded and what's in the zip content:
https://ibb.co/3vwsbft
https://ibb.co/JsdybY8
My project folder main doesn't have a Plugins folder, I made one but I'm unsure what to put in it since the zip seems to be more than for plugins. I really do appreciate any help because the project I'm working on is in desperate need of DLSS to have some decent frame rate.
